# Find index of specific column in R

Tags: r, matrix

Consider the following matrix:

```
 mat = rbind(c(".","2","3","4","5","6"), 
             c(".","2","3","7","8","1"), 
             c(".","2","3","7","9","2"))
```

I would like to find the index of the first column of which all the elements are different. In this case, the result should be **5**. As you can see, the column five is the first columns for which all the elements are different.

In reality, the matrix has very large dimensions.

Is there an easy way of retrieving the index of the first columns for which all elements are different?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do something like:

```
which(apply(mat, 2, function(x) all(!duplicated(x))))[1]
[1] 5
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks! But for some reason, it works fine with the above example, but not so fine with my real matrix..

Comment: Then you should extend your question with a realistic example that reproduces the problems you have.

Comment: Well the matrix I posted is literally a subset of my big matrix.

Comment: Then expand your example until you reproduce the problems you have with your real data. Right now we only know that 'it does not work' for you, and that leaves us just clueless as to what is going wrong.

Comment: Ok. Thank you anyways, your solution is clever.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of `all(!duplicated(x))` you could also use `anyDuplicated`, e.g.:

```
which(apply(mat, 2, anyDuplicated) == 0)[1]
[1] 5
```

According to `?anyDuplicated` it should be more efficient:

> ‘anyDuplicated(.)’ is a “generalized” more efficient shortcut for
>        ‘any(duplicated(.))’

Comment: shorter but not equivalent, in the event the matrix has no such column with all unique values.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an alternative

```
> which(apply(mat, 2, function(x) all(!duplicated(x)))==TRUE)[1]
[1] 5
```

Comment: @PaulHiemstra you're right. I will not edit since you already posted it as an answer  ;)

Answer (score 3):

You could avoid turning all columns into logical and then selecting the *first* `TRUE`. You could use a simple `for` loop and a `break` wrapped in a function like this:

```
findfirst <- function(mat)
{
 for(i in seq_len(ncol(mat))) {
    if(!anyDuplicated(mat[,i])) break 
 }
 return(i)
}
findfirst(mat)
#[1] 5
```

Comment: I would actually guess that this would be a pretty good approach instead of checking all the columns...

Answer (score 2):

The tools you are looking for are apply() and unique().
My solution checks which matrix is of the correct length:

```
apply(mat, 2, function(x) length(unique(x))==length(x))
```

If you would like to use this to get only the first full column,

```
answers<-mat[,apply(mat, 2, function(x) length(unique(x))==length(x))]
answers[,1]
```

Answer (score 0):

All the other solutions are nicer than mine, but I thought I'd post my ugly answer anyway.

```
min(which(lapply(sapply(apply(mat,2,rle),'[[',1),function(x)all(x==1))==T))
```